# Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, timeout

I would like to show divs at a specific interval (10 seconds) and show next div and as go on and repeat the same.

**

> ***Sequence :***

**
On 10th second
show div1 , hide other divs ,
After 5seconds interval 
Show div 2 and hide other divs, 
After 5 seconds interval
Show div 3 and hide other divs, 
 
and repeat the same for every 10 seconds.

---

> ***Code Follows:***

---

```
<div id='div1' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>

<div id='div2' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>

<div id='div3' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/acumo)** here - add **/edit** to the URL to play with the code

You just need to use JavaScript [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval) function

```js
$('html').addClass('js');

$(function() {

  var timer = setInterval(showDiv, 5000);

  var counter = 0;

  function showDiv() {
    if (counter == 0) {
      counter++;
      return;
    }

    $('div', '#container')
      .stop()
      .hide()
      .filter(function() {
        return this.id.match('div' + counter);
      })
      .show('fast');
    counter == 3 ? counter = 0 : counter++;

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      font: 16px Helvetica, Arial;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .display {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 2px solid #000;
    }
    
    .js .display {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Example of using setInterval to trigger display of Div</h2>
  <p>The first div will display after 10 seconds...</p>
  <div id='container'>
    <div id='div1' class='display' style="background-color: red;">
      div1
    </div>
    <div id='div2' class='display' style="background-color: green;">
      div2
    </div>
    <div id='div3' class='display' style="background-color: blue;">
      div3
    </div>
    <div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment about the container div, just modify this

```
$('div','#container')
```

to this

```
$('#div1, #div2, #div3')
```

Comment: Russ Thanks for the quick reply to the post. In your example it shows we need to have a div container and in to that we need to have other divs.. But my divs are not inside to an container its seperate. how to modify the code accordingly ?

Comment: do you have access to modify the HTML? If so, I would suggest wrapping the divs in a container div for context and ease of selection. Without a container div, the code would need to be modified to select only those divs in question i.e. divs with ids 1, 2 and 3. I'll update my answer now

Comment: Ya makes sense i can have it in a container div for better clarity.
Russ tell me can we show another div (named : div_sub1) at the time of displaying div1 and subsequently.Will the same code can be resued ?

Comment: Sure. There's a number of ways of tackling that scenario, you could use an attribute match on the id to show div_sub1 at the same time as div1, you could chain it onto the visibility of div1, to name a couple of solutions.

Comment: P.S. I have also provide a solution to your other question using an anchor to toggle showing different divs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914558/using-jquery-how-to-show-and-hide-different-divs-onclick-event/914793#914793

Comment: Russ for an understanding can you explain what this line does
 .filter( function() { return this.id.match('div' + counter); })   

Thanks.

Comment: the $('div','#container') selector selects all divs in the context of the element with container id. Then all of the matched elements are hidden, then we want to filter the matched elements to only elements whose id matches 'div' + the value of counter (in this case, only one element will match) and then show the filtered elements

Comment: Hi. I can't uderstand ther is can i change initial time 10s? I have the same case but i need to show 1 Div at the start

Answer (score 23):

Loop through divs every 10 seconds.

```
$(function () {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');

    function showDiv () {
        divs.hide() // hide all divs
            .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
            .show('fast'); // and show it

        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

    showDiv(); // show first div    

    setInterval(function () {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 10 * 1000); // do this every 10 seconds    

});
```

Comment: is there a way to change the layout to, show div1 then show div2 and still show div1 at the same time. So when div2 comes it shows div1 and div2?

Answer (score 8):

here is a jQuery plugin I came up with:

```
$.fn.cycle = function(timeout){
    var $all_elem = $(this)

    show_cycle_elem = function(index){
        if(index == $all_elem.length) return; //you can make it start-over, if you want
        $all_elem.hide().eq(index).fadeIn()
        setTimeout(function(){show_cycle_elem(++index)}, timeout);
    }
    show_cycle_elem(0);
}
```

You need to have a common classname for all the divs you wan to cycle, use it like this:

```
$("div.cycleme").cycle(5000)
```

Answer (score 5):

See [InnerFade](http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(

    function() {
        $('#portfolio').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 10000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '220px'
        });
    });
</script>
<ul id="portfolio">
    <li>
        <a href="http://medienfreunde.com/deutsch/referenzen/kreation/good_guy__bad_guy.html">
        <img src="images/ggbg.gif" alt="Good Guy bad Guy" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://medienfreunde.com/deutsch/referenzen/kreation/whizzkids.html">
        <img src="images/whizzkids.gif" alt="Whizzkids" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://medienfreunde.com/deutsch/referenzen/printdesign/koenigin_mutter.html">
        <img src="images/km.jpg" alt="Königin Mutter" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://medienfreunde.com/deutsch/referenzen/webdesign/rt_reprotechnik_-_hybride_archivierung.html">
        <img src="images/rt_arch.jpg" alt="RT Hybride Archivierung" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://medienfreunde.com/deutsch/referenzen/kommunikation/tuev_sued_gruppe.html">
        <img src="images/tuev.jpg" alt="TÜV SÜD Gruppe" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a another take on this problem, using recursion and without using mutable variables. Also, im not using `setInterval` so theres no cleanup that has to be done.

Having this HTML

```
<section id="testimonials">
    <h2>My testimonial spinner</h2>
    <div class="testimonial">
      <p>First content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
      <p>Second content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
       <p>Third content</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Using ES2016

Here you call the function recursively and update the arguments.

```
  const testimonials = $('#testimonials')
      .children()
      .filter('div.testimonial');

  const showTestimonial = index => {

    testimonials.hide();
    $(testimonials[index]).fadeIn();

    return index === testimonials.length
      ? showTestimonial(0)
      : setTimeout(() => { showTestimonial(index + 1); }, 10000);
   }

showTestimonial(0); // id of the first element you want to show.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      $('document').ready(function(){
         window.setTimeout('test()',time in milliseconds);
      });

      function test(){

      $('#divid').hide();

      }
```