# change script: Loop through divs every 10 seconds PLUS select DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, timeout

on the page 
[Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery)

there is a script to Loop through DIVs (show 1 DIV after the other whil hiding the others).

it#s called "Loop through divs every 10 seconds "

It works fine, but i need to select a special DIV with a click on a special button.

There are 3 DIVS with headline 1 - 2 - 3 (the active is RED)
The Loop-Script changes the DIVs and shows them right. BUt whe click on 2 the DIV Nr. 2 should become active. (and the Loop should go on with Nr. 3 - 1 - 2....

Can anybody help?!?

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: can't you just give special divs special classes and when you click the button, show only the ones with the special class and hide others

Comment: @Martin, don't add a new question in an edit, please ask a new question, if you want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

here it is!

```
$(".button").click(function(){

       counter = 3//specific number you need;
       showDiv()
});
```