# Show and Hide divs (with some delay) using setInterval (infinite loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval, show-hide

If anyone can help me , I want this js process on one of my page:

> - Delay of 60 sec;
> - Show my div 1 for 20 sec;
> - Delay of 60 sec;
> - Show my div 2 for 20 sec;
> - Delay of 60 sec;
> - Show my div 1 for 20 sec;
> - Delay of 60 sec;
> - Show my div 2 for 20 sec;
> - .
> - .
> - continue forever...

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery)! which I found at 'StockOverFlow' but not working correctly for me.

Thank You

Comment: Actually that solution should work great if you replace `5000` with `20000` and `counter == 3` with `counter == 2`. What exactly is not working?

Comment: The problem there is that I want some delay in between Div 1 & Div 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that will do that:

HTML:

```
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var shortIntervalTime = 2 * 1000;
var longIntervalTime = 5 * 1000;

function cycle(id) {
    var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2": "block1";
    $("#" + id)
        .delay(shortIntervalTime)
        .fadeIn(500)
        .delay(longIntervalTime)
        .fadeOut(500, function() {cycle(nextId)});
}

cycle("block1");
```

You can set the interval times to whatever you would like - I have them set short here for demo purposes.  This uses a sequence of jQuery effects and then upon the completion of the last effect on a given object, it starts the cycle over again on the other object and repeats forever.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LTRzV/.

Comment: Thanks 'jfriend00' for the quick reply. I was busy during the last couple of days so ran the code today and also saw the demo.

The only thing which I want to know that why it is taking 2 seconds more to hide while running 'longIntervalTime', if it is set to 7500 then it fads out at 9500. You can notice it in your demo.

Excuse my poor English.

Comment: The times are cumulative.  In the demo, it's a 2.5 second delay, 0.5 second fadeIn, 7.5 second delay, 0.5 second fadeOut.

Comment: o' hmm ! 1 more question, the timer in the demo starts from 0 , is it possible to get it going in opposite direction (like 7.5 to 0)?