# How to stop a jQuery script

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery)

I have a jQuery script what is showing and hiding divs at a specific interval. It's working fine but I have one problem, its showing and hiding divs round and round so basically its never stops.
How can I make this stop? Lets say it stops after showing 3x the divs.

```
$(function() {
    var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 5000);    
    var counter = 0;

    function showDiv() {
        if (counter == 0) { 
            counter++; 
            return; 
        }

        $('div','#container')
            .stop()
            .hide()
            .filter( function() { return this.id.match('div' + counter); })   
            .show('fast');

        counter == 3? counter = 0 : counter++; 
    }
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Comment: Seems like you copy-pasted some code from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/q/915016/508702 and now wonder why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

  var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 5000);

  var counter = 0;
  var showTimes = 3;
  function showDiv() {
    if (counter ==0) { counter++; return; }

    $('div','#container')
      .stop()
      .hide()
      .filter( function() { return this.id.match('div' + counter); })   
      .show('fast');

    if(counter == 3){
       counter = 0;
       showTimes--;
       if(showTimes == 0)
           clearInterval(timer);
    }else{
       counter++; 
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: thank you Niels, its working perfectly. sorry but my reputation is too low to vote up your answer.

Comment: You can pick it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

add your whole code into a function and call that function within a for loop only thrice with the time interval

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` as you are using it now. When you want the timer to stop you call `clearInterval`, passing it the timer you got from the setInterval call.  You can do this inside your `showDiv` function if you like.