# Make a div block with with fading elements disappear and reappear after a set time

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to make a div disappear and reappear after a set amount of time.

Inside the div are div elements that fade in and fade out.

I thought this would work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$( "#productDiv" ).removeAttr( "style" ).show().fadeIn();
}, 1000 );
```

but it isn't so I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong. I also can't figure out how to show the div again after a set time.

Can anyone take a look at this and give me pointers?

http://jsfiddle.net/linuxbastard/nGCNJ/5/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reffer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery

This would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :- this will chain the effect after every 2secs

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#productDiv").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
    }, 2000 );
 });
```

Comment: Hi Subhajit, that works! I should have used `setInterval` in the first place. LOL. [Finished code](http://jsfiddle.net/linuxbastard/nGCNJ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
$("#productDiv").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn();
```

This hides the div, and program the fadeIn effect to be applied 1000 ms after that. That's the natural and idiomatic way to chain jquery effects.

Comment: hi dystroy, I've done that before but as you indicated it starts the div hidden. reversing it with `$("productDiv").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();` starts it visible and then fades out, but don't know how to chain a timed fade in after that and loop it.