# jquery jshowoff different timing per div?

Tags: jquery

I've got a page that currently has 3 divs and I'm using jshowoff to rotate the three divs currently at 30 seconds per div. My question is, is there a way of getting one div to display for a different amount of time than the other divs?

e.g. div 1 - 30 seconds, div 2 - 2 minutes, div 3 - 30 seconds?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to accept only 1 value for the `speed` parameter, so it's unlikely possible without some hacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `setTimeout()`. Here is a Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Um94/2/

```
   $('#features').jshowoff({ speed:1500, links: false }); });

   setTimeout(function(){
     $("div.mydiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $("div.mydiv").remove();
     });

   }, 2000);
```

You can se the time by changing `2000` to your preferred value, note this value is in milliseconds. So 2000 = 2seconds.

Also, take a look at this similar question that might help you: [Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery)

Comment: I think this is going to be the easiest road I go down!

Comment: I've then also combined it with http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/ to refresh the final div which is going to be on screen for half an hour but needs refreshing every few minutes