# Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery but stop the last div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need code to automatically hide `div1` and show `div2` after a specific amount of time, say 10sec or 15sec.
I read this post :
[Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery?answertab=oldest#tab-top),

but it repeats every 10 seconds. I just need to hide `div1` and show `div2` once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your divs have the ids `"div1"` and `"div2`", and that `"div1"` starts out visible and `"div2"` starts out hidden, then you can hide the first and show the second after *x* milliseconds like this:

```
$("#div1").delay(10000).hide(0, function() {
    $("#div2").show();
});
```

You can use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` or other animation methods instead of `.hide()` and `.show()` if you like.

Put the above code inside a document ready handler if the intention is for this to happen automatically, or in a click handler or whatever if it is in response to something the user does.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s7NXz/

If you have more than two divs and you want to cycle through them exactly once you can do something like this:

```
var $divs = $("div").hide(),    // use an appropriate selector here
    current = 0;

$divs.eq(0).show();             // show the first

function showNext() {
    if (current < $divs.length - 1) { // if not past the end then
        $divs.eq(current).delay(2000).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            current++;
            $divs.eq(current).fadeIn('fast');
            showNext();
        });
    }
}
showNext();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s7NXz/1/

Answer (score 1):

First `div1` is visible and `div2` is hidden. To show `div2` and hide `div1` after a specific time, you can add a common class, `x`:

```
 $('.x').delay(1000).toggle();
```

You can adjust delay and toggle speed. Toggle will display matching hidden elements and hide matching shown elements.
See [jQuery toggle docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').addClass('js');

$(function() {

  var timer = setTimeout( showDiv, 5000);

  var counter = 0;

  function showDiv() {
    if (counter ==0) { counter++; return; }

    $('div','#container')
      .stop()
      .hide()
      .filter( function() { return this.id.match('div' + counter); })   
      .show('fast');
    counter == 3? counter = 0 : counter++; 

  }

});
```

use setTimeout in place of setInterval

Comment: Thanks you, but how to stop at last div??

Answer (score -1):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").hide(1000);
  alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

Comment: Code-only answer is not encouraged, the answer value increase when you add some context to explain how this will solve the problem