# how to load the contents of div at some time interval

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, function, pull-to-refresh

This is a javascript function through which i call iframe.
But what i want is before i call an iframe i refresh or call or update the contents of a div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshConversatio() {

            document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').src = 'frmMessageDisplay.aspx?id=' + document.getElementById('val').value+'&id1=' + document.getElementById('HiddenTime').value,
            document.getElementById('iframe1').src = 'frmChatRequest.aspx',
            document.getElementById('iframe2').src = 'PendingChat.aspx';


        }

    </script>
```

This is the div

```
<div id="divItem">
     <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="val"  name="val" />
      <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="HiddenTime" name="HiddenTime" />  
</div>
```

and this is the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function () { refreshConversatio(); }, 3000)


    </script>
```

Comment: your requirement is not so clear to me, do you want to update  DOM under div (id="divItem")  before calling the function "refreshConversatio()" ?

Comment: yes thats wat i want refresh the  value of hidden field before calling the function

Comment: if you want to update DOM at client side(using javascript) the wrire the code inside setInterval Callback function before calling refreshConversatio()---- setInterval(function () {  --*write here*--  refreshConversatio(); }, 3000)----

Comment: You may find some help here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery