# Show and hide effect of div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div which should be hidden initially. Then on some event (doesn't matter) I want my div to slide up, stay for several seconds and slide down again. How could I achieve this.

Comment: Can you please provide some markup to demonstrate what you've achieved already?

Comment: look at css `display` property, then [slidedown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) and `setTimeout()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)**, **[`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)** and **[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**

```js
function anim() {
  $('div')
    // stop any previous animation
    .stop()
    // slide up the div
    .slideUp()
    // wait for 2 seconds
    .delay(2000)
    // slide down the div
    .slideDown();
}

anim();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background:black"></div>
```

---

Or using **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** instead of **[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**

```js
function anim() {
  var $div = $('div')
    // stop any previous animation
    .stop()
    // slide up the div
    .slideUp();
  // wait for 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    // slide down the div
    $div.slideDown()
  }, 2000);
}

anim();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background:black"></div>
```